# Socket io: best practices (number of event listeners, number of rooms, etc)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am new in using socket io and was just wondering about different aspects of using this module.

1) Number of event listeners:
How expensive is it to add event listeners? Is it better to add more events and handle them or one event and pass a type attribute in the data to differentiate between different topics. for example:

In a chat example, i can add event listeners for
* add-text 
* remove-text 
* edit text 
. However i can also add one listener: 'chat-updates' and pass in the sent data a type attribute:

```
{ type: 'add-text' (or whatever), text: .... }
```

which one is considered as best practise?!!

2) Number of rooms:
how many rooms can i establish would it be ok to create thousands of rooms?

3) When to use rooms and when to use namespaces?

Thanks